# How to fix 'Invalid Property Name ' in kivy

Tags: python, kivy

in line 7 it throws the error:

## :kivy 1.0.9

:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    spacing: 10

```
BoxLayout:
    size_hint_y= None
    height: 50
    Label:
        text: 'Account Control'
        bold: True
        size_hint_x=.9
    Button:
         text: 'x'
         size_hint_x= 1
```

6:    BoxLayout:

> > 7:        size_hint_y= None
> >            8:        height: 50
> >            9:        Label:
> >      ...
> >      Invalid property name

Answer (score 0):

This usually indicates a syntax error messing up the property name parsing. In this case, your error is on the line you picked out: `size_hint_x= 1` should be `size_hint_x: 1`.